# Linking an image source based on base64

Tags: javascript, html, image, base64

I've been working on a chatroom project using node.js with the ability to send images. I was able to convert the image uploaded by the user, but I want to make it so that when you click it, it opens the source into a new tab. However, when I click it, it opens in an about:blank page. When I check the console of the about:blank page, I get this error message:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND8Ef.png)

Here's the code I used for the source and the link.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQiMP.png)

Anyone know what the issue is? Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get around it and achieve the same thing..

```
<html>

    <script>
    
        function openDataUrl(base64URL){
            let aWindow = window.open();

            aWindow.document.write('<iframe src="' + base64URL  + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        }
    
    </script>

    <body>
        <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="openDataUrl('data:image/png;base64,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
T5uP1IQxToyOAZiQu5HEpjeA4SWIoksRxNiGC1tRZJ4LNxgHgnU5nJZBDvuDdl8lzQRBsQ+s9PZt7s7Pz8wsL39/DkIfZ4xlB2Gqsq62ta9oxVlVrNZpihFRpGO9fzQw1ms0NDWZz07iGkJmIFH8xxkc3a/WWlubmFkv9AB2SEpDvKxbjidN2faseaNV3zoHXvv7wMODJdkOHAegweAfFPx4G67KluxzottCU9n8CUqXzcIQdXOytAHqXxomvykhEKN9EFutG22p//0rbNvHVxiJywa8yS2KDfV1dfbu31H8jF1RHiTKtWYeHxUvq3bn0pyjCRaiRU6aDO+gb3aEfEeVNsDgm8zzLy9egPa7Qt8TSJdwhjplk06HH43ZNJ3s91KKCHQ5x4sw1fRGYDZ0n1L4FKb9/BP5JLYxToheoFCVxz57PPS8UhhEpLBVeAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC')">Open</a>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. If I'm correct, does it get the URL and open it in a new window using an iframe as the image source?

Comment: I ended up doing something like this:





    var linky = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+Base64String.decompress(img)+'" style="width:100%;">';
      msg = msg.replace('<img>', `<a href="javascript:void();" onclick='let aWindow = window.open();aWindow.document.write(\``+linky+`\`)'> <img class="chat-img" src="data:image/png;base64,` + Base64String.decompress(img) + '" alt="image"></a>')